# Using DDP in Angular 4 Application

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor, ddp, rocket.chat

I am Angular 4 developer. Want to include RocketChat Engine developed in MeteorJS. By research I got to know that it will need DDP(Protocol) to connect Angular4 with Meteor.

I am unable to find any DDP package which allows me to integrate with Angular4 TypeScript.

Can you please help me out in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a plain DDP packages. Probably the most popular one is [mondora's asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid).

But you could also use Meteor's own packages.

The advantages are that they are better maintained and also they include not only DDP but also a local cache implementations and Mongo API on the client.

You don't need to use the Meteor build system for that, here is [a blog post](https://blog.meteor.com/leverage-the-power-of-meteor-with-any-client-side-framework-bfb909141008) about [meteor-client-bundler](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-client-bundler).

Once you have that, the best way to integrate Meteor's DDP with Angular is through [Meteor-RxjS](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs).

Here is a [simple example](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/examples/angularcli-meteor) using the AngularCLI and a [tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup) that uses Ionic. -  and here you can check out a small example with the Angular CLI.

As a side note, it looks like the future protocol you would want to use is GraphQL and GraphQL-Subscriptions for real time.

We've recently made a PR for RocketChat to support GraphQL - https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/pull/8158
I hope they will merge that soon.

In this PR you can check out an AngularCLI with PWA that uses RocketChat's new GraphQL API - https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.PWA/pull/32

Comment: I have installed meteor-client-bundler and meteor-rxjs on the client side and trying to use MongoObservable to call the collections but getting namespace error for meteor and mongo.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction and post it as an issue on the repo?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ddp-client packages. Among them is https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client

Basically they allow you to communicate with a Meteor server over DDP.

I'll let you look through them and decide which suits you

Comment: Yes. I have found this package. But its in Pure Node. I am using **Angular 4** with **TypeScript**. So I need a package which allows me to write code in **TypeScript** and connect to Meteor Server.

I have found this package with TypeScript:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-ddp-client

which is giving me some errors.

Can you help me out to find package?